# windows 2012 r2 remote users unable to write CDs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, removable-storage

We have an environment where multiple regular users share a single windows 2012 R2 server via RDP as their "workstation". I'd like to allow them to use an attached CD burner from time to time.

I've followed the instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731422(v=ws.10).aspx for enabling **All Removable Storage: Allow direct access in remote sessions**, but it does not seem to work.

The disc drive for users and even users in the Administrators group shows up, but does not show the progress bar icon under the drive indicating it is writable. It does not make a difference if logged in locally via KVM or through RDP.

[image: DVD RW Drive not writable]

When they double click on the drive icon it shows:

> Windows can't read the disc in drive E:\
>       Make sure that the disc uses a format that Windows recognizes...

If I log in as the "Administrator" (Local or Domain), or if I kill all my explorer.exe processes and start one new from the elevated command prompt the drive shows up as one would expect. This works locally via KVM or via RDP.

[image: DVD RW Drive writable]

When I log in as an administrative user via RDP or even local on the KVM the only way I can see the CD Burner dialogue is if I am the "Administrator" user or if I kill all explorer.exe processes for myself and start a new one from an elevated prompt.

I've done all I can think of in terms of setting the group policy from our domain controller, un-setting it at the DC and setting it locally on our server, rebooting between each change, and still regular users can't burn discs!

I know there must be a way because it works how I want on another network we use but the group policy settings there are what I would expect the **All Removable Storage: Allow direct access in remote sessions** is enabled and there are no configured values for the "Deny..." device options.

Any tips here would be appreciated as it is driving me crazy that it works on one of our networks but not the other!